# deploying django react on digitalocean with nginx gunicorn

Tags: django, reactjs, nginx, gunicorn

i have bind react build inside django. its working fine on localhost but on server its static files not working. when i run this after activating virtualenv:

```
gunicorn --bind 64.225.24.226:8000 liveimage.wsgi
```

its admin panel working without css:
[image: admin panel]

this is my nginx default config:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name 64.225.24.226;

access_log off;
location /media/ {
alias /root/liveimage/media/;  # change project_name
 }
location /static {
 autoindex on;
 alias /root/liveimage/build;
}
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
}
```

}

my seetings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'social_django.context_processors.backends',
            'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
        ],
    },
},
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/static')] 


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

gunicorn.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target
[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/root/liveimage
ExecStart=/root/venv/bin/gunicorn \
      --access-logfile - \
      --workers 3 \
      --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
      liveimage.wsgi:application
 [Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

my project is in /root/liveimage and virtualenv at /root/venv
i dont know what going wrong

Comment: do you have the static files in `/root/liveimage/build`?

Comment: no its in static folder

Comment: Before gunicorn --bind, did you run python manage.py collectstatic ?

Comment: i also tried with /root/liveimage/static

Comment: yes i did run collectstatic is the static directory right or i should add /root/liveimage/static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gunicorn will not show styling.

I found this :

> Note: The admin interface will not have any of the styling applied since Gunicorn does not know how to find the static CSS content responsible for this.

From the [docs](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: its saying you need to enable javascript

Comment: Where? In the admin panel?

Comment: gunicorn --bind 64.225.24.226:8000 liveimage.wsgi can be used to test if gunicorn can serve the application or not. To get all the css, you need to configure nginx. It is in the mentioned docs in the answer(Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: gunicorn --bind 64.225.24.226:8000 liveimage.wsgi its not loading anything even without css

Comment: What is the image in the question?

Comment: its a image model

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204192/discussion-between-srijwal-r-and-afk).

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know Nginx configuration, but the key here is that Django doesn't serve static files in production, they must be served by Nginx.

On your site, go to your browser's dev tools -> network -> click css, and look at the urls. They must target the static directory generated by `manage.py collectstatic` and Nginx must serve the content of that directory from those urls.